# Ground isolation

Tags: ground, grounding, isolation

I am looking at ways to isolate my board and supply ground. I am feeding my board with a 40V dc power source. Now, the ground return of my board should not be connected to the battery return is the suggestion from the customer. Now, to isolate the ground I know we can use a transformer. But transformer works on ac. I don't want to  use a dc dc converter or is it the only way forward. ? My board draws about 3-4amps of current. What are ways I can provide a ground isolation ? The battery is connected to multiple boards in parralel, so they probably don't want to curropt the main ground and cause noise from one board to creep into another board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU6dpT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above is the schematic that the client has shown/recommended .

Comment: There's a schematic editor button on the toolbar. Add in a block diagram of your layout showing the transformer, battery and various grounds.

Comment: It all boils down to why the customer is saying "Now, the ground return of my board should not be connected to the battery return is the suggestion from the customer". I can guess why but you need to paint the bigger picture.

Comment: If you want to isolate the GND, isolate the power line as well.

Comment: Yes, both power and ground. But how can I do that using a transformer ? Transformers work on ac to dc. In my case it's a battery input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly need galvanic isolation, then, at that power level, a transformer-based DC-DC converter is your only practical option.  If that is unacceptable for cost/space/weight/whatever reasons, then as @Andyaka indicated, you need to examine what's really going on and whether you really need galvanic isolation or just better management of your ground currents.  That's about as much of an answer as you're likely to get unless you can provide more information about what's really going on.